# YouTrack installation Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, console, youtrack

I installed YouTrack following [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Install-YouTrack-JAR-as-Service-Linux.html).

But I can't reach the service. If a show the service status, i get the following:

```
youtrack.service - LSB: initscript for youtrack
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/youtrack; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-09-28 13:08:47 CEST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4544 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/youtrack stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 4570 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/youtrack start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC

Sep 28 13:08:47 k003715vsa systemd[1]: Starting LSB: initscript for youtrack...
Sep 28 13:08:47 k003715vsa youtrack[4570]: Starting youtrack...
Sep 28 13:08:47 k003715vsa su[4573]: Successful su for youtrack by root
Sep 28 13:08:47 k003715vsa su[4573]: + ??? root:youtrack
Sep 28 13:08:47 k003715vsa su[4573]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for us
Sep 28 13:08:47 k003715vsa systemd[1]: Started LSB: initscript for youtrack.
```

Comment: Have you checked application log files? One can found them in ~/.youtrack/logs

Comment: In this directory, I only have a directory with hub, in which are error logs, but these errors are over two weeks old, even tried to restart the service, but there are no new error messages.

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me on a xubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. This procedure  can be performed on a headless machine (no GUI is needed). I used the standalone installation.

- Download the standalone zip and place it into the `~/Downloads` folder. I used this link:

  https://download.jetbrains.com/charisma/youtrack-2018.1.40840.zip
- Create a sudo user:

  `sudo adduser youtrack`

  ```
  [sudo] password for xubuntu:
  Adding user 'youtrack' ...
  Adding new group 'youtrack' (1001) ...
  Adding new user 'youtrack' (1001) with group 'youtrack' ...
  Creating home directory '/home/youtrack' ...
  Copying files from '/etc/skel' ...
  Enter new UNIX password:
  Retype new UNIX password:
  passwd: password updated successfully
  Changing the user information for youtrack
  Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
  Full Name []: youtrack
  Room Number []:
  Work Phone []:
  Home Phone []:
  Other []:
  Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
  ```

  `sudo usermod -aG sudo youtrack`
- Unzip the standalone zip to /usr/share/youtrack:

  ```
  cd /usr/share
  sudo unzip ~/Downloads/youtrack-2018.1.40840.zip
  sudo mv youtrack-2018.1.40840 youtrack
  sudo chown -R youtrack:youtrack youtrack
  ```
- Start youtrack:

  ```
  su youtrack -c '/usr/share/youtrack/bin/youtrack.sh start --no-browser'
  ```

  (use the password of youtrack user here)

  ```
  Starting YouTrack...
  ...
  ...
  * JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 Configuration Wizard will be available on 
  [http://xubuntu-virtualbox:8080/?wizard_token=SGM7TEOeaYyswF2HHWrD] after start
  YouTrack is running
  ```
- Open your browser. You can use a browser on an other machine. As mentioned, you don't need a gui on this machine. Then navigate to the given URI.
- Follow the wizard:

  `Set up` -> `Base URL:` key in the IP of the youtrack machine (this is the IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` that is used bellow for connecting after the configuration is finished)  -> `Next` -> use admin password -> `Next` -> `Finish` -> wait for a while until YouTrack dashboard is loaded.
- From now on you need an IP without a wizard_token in order to connect (wizard_token is only needed for the initial configuration). In order to find out the new IP:

  ```
  su youtrack -c '/usr/share/youtrack/bin/youtrack.sh stop'
  ```

  (use the password of youtrack user here)

  ```
  su youtrack -c '/usr/share/youtrack/bin/youtrack.sh start --no-browser'
  ```

  (use the password of youtrack user here)

  ```
  Starting YouTrack...
  ...
  ...
  * JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 will be available on
  [http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/bundle/starting] after start
  * Starting YouTrack Configurator
  YouTrack is running
  ```
- Use this link in order to load YouTrack dashboard:
  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/bundle/starting
- If you want YouTrack to start automatically after rebooting:

  ```
  sudo sed -i 's/exit 0/su youtrack -c "\/usr\/share\/youtrack\/bin\/youtrack.sh start --no-browser"\nexit 0/g' /etc/rc.local
  ```

I hope this works for you.